# Show that: $f : \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R} ; \ x \mapsto \cos^2(x)$ is measurable with respect to the Lebesgue measure space

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

How can I show that  $f : \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R} ; \     x \mapsto \cos^2(x)$
 is measurable with respect to the Lebesgue measure space?

My first thought is that it should be Borel-measurable, so if I can prove that, then it is obviously Lebesgue-measurable, but I'm  not sure how to start the proof. Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Every continuous function is Borel-measurable.

Comment: The @drhab comment is a hint of how to start.  It is probably just as easy to prove every continuous function is Borel measurable as it is to prove $\cos^2 x$ is Borel measurable.

Comment: You can also take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3221281/75923).

Comment: Perfect, thanks, that should do it.